# How to repair win7 boot?

Tags: boot, windows-7

I use win7 + ubuntu 14.04.

I'm not sure how to cause this problem.

The situation is I can see boot menu with win7 but without working.

When I press enter on win7, it splash and show the same menu again to let me choose.

What's this situation?

How to fixed it?

Thank you~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first try this:

- insert your windows 7 instalation cd/dvd and boot from. choose your language and hit next. when prompted to "install now" appear just look left down to that windos and press repair your computer.
- wait and a new windows rise with operatings system instaled in your pc. click on "windows 7" and  hit next.
- in the next window press "Command "Prompt". when command prompt window appear type that:

  ```
  bootrec /fixboot
  ```

  press enter and:

  ```
  bootrec /fixmbr
  ```
- press enter again and then close that command prompt window and restart your pc.
  Note: between "bootrec" and "/" there is a space, dont forget.
- After that i think you will no longer have option to choose between operating systems to boot on startup. you will must to repair grub.( i think you can do that with ubuntu live cd. but i am not sure.
  Good luck. Let me know if you fix that.
  (Easy way is after repair windows 7 boot format the linux partition and reinstall linux:D)

Note :

01/20/2019

To repair grub after fix windows 7 boot:

Try this..
To recover grub:
1.Open the live version.

2.Open the terminal and run 
sudo fdisk -l
 to see where Linux is installed.

3.Run:
sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt
 where X is the number you have found Linux word in

4.Run: 
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda

to install grub.

5.Run: 
sudo update-grub to update grub, and if this command didn't work run it after rebooting.

6.Reboot.

Note:

For me #5 command didn't work. So i restart the computer and after restart, computer boot directly in  to ubuntu O.S. 
So i loged as root  and write this command:

sudo update-grub

That solve the problem.
 EugenB